# Magento2 - New customer address attribute won't save to database

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer-address

I'm trying to define a new customer address attribute that will be available in all the customer address forms (backend, frontend, checkout). I've used the information provided here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

I've also read and tried to apply a lot of posts and articles I found in sources like Stack Exchange and in other websites found via Google. So far I've managed to get the attribute in all forms, but the value is only saved to the database in the admin address form; in the frontend address forms (customer section and checkout section) the attribute value is simply ignored. All the posts, articles and answers I've checked haven't helped. Could anyone please tell me if I'm missing something?

Here are all the relevant code snippets:

1.- Install script:

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
  public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
  ) {
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'address_email', array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Address E-mail',
            'global' => 1,
            'visible' => 1,
            'required' => 0,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system'=> 0,
            'group'=> 'General',
            'visible_on_front' => 1,
        ));
        $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'address_email')
            ->setUsedInForms(array('adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address', 'customer_address'))
            ->save();
  }
}
```

2.- di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Rokanthemes\OpCheckout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="changeAddressFields" type="Vendor\AddressCustomization\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100" disabled="false"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper">
    <plugin name="move-extension-attributes" type="Vendor\AddressCustomization\Plugin\Api\DataObjectHelper" sortOrder="20"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info">
    <plugin name="render-address-email" type="Vendor\AddressCustomization\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" sortOrder="20"/>
</type>
```

3.- Plugins

```
namespace Vendor\AddressCustomization\Plugin\Api;    

class DataObjectHelper
    {
        public function beforePopulateWithArray($helper, $dataObject, array $data, $interfaceName)
        {
            switch ($interfaceName) {
                case 'Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface':
                    if (isset($data['extension_attributes']) && ($data['extension_attributes'] instanceof \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface)) {
                        $data['extension_attributes'] = $data['extension_attributes']->__toArray();
                    }
                break;
                case 'Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface':
                    if (isset($data['extension_attributes']) && ($data['extension_attributes'] instanceof \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface)) {
                        $data['extension_attributes'] = $data['extension_attributes']->__toArray();
                        if (isset($data['extension_attributes']['address_email'])){
                            $data['address_email'] = $data['extension_attributes']['address_email'];
                        }
                        if (isset($data['extension_attributes']['is_company'])){
                            $data['is_company'] = $data['extension_attributes']['is_company'];
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface':
                    unset($data['extension_attributes']);
                    break;
            }
            return array($dataObject, $data, $interfaceName);
        }
    }
```

-

```
namespace Vendor\AddressCustomization\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

class Info
{
    public function beforeGetFormattedAddress($block, $address)
    {
        if ($attributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes()) {
            $address->setAddressEmail($attributes->getAddressEmail());
        }
        return array($address);
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace Vendor\AddressCustomization\Plugin\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
  ....
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    )
    {
      ....
        $customAttributes = array(
            'address_email' => array(
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'additionalClasses' => 'one-field',
                    'placeholder' => 'Shipping destination e-mail',
                    // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'customEntry' => null,
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.address_email',
                'label' => __('Destination E-mail'),
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'sortOrder' => 1000,
                'validation' => [
                    'required-entry' => false
                ],
                'options' => [],
                'filterBy' => null,
                'customEntry' => null,
                'visible' => false,
            ),
        );
        foreach ($customAttributes as $customAttributeCode => $customField) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;
        }
    }
}
```

4.- Javascript mixins

```
file app/code/Vendor/AddressCustomization/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js    

var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Vendor_AddressCustomization/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

-

```
file app/code/Vendor/AddressCustomization/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js

/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }
            if (shippingAddress.customAttributes === undefined) {
                shippingAddress.customAttributes = {};
            }

            if (shippingAddress.customAttributes['address_email'] instanceof Object) {
                shippingAddress.customAttributes['address_email'] = shippingAddress.customAttributes['address_email'].value;
            }
            shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['address_email'] = shippingAddress.customAttributes['address_email'];

            // pass execution to original action ('Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information')
            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

5.- Extension attributes

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="address_email" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface">
        <attribute code="address_email" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="address_email" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check below code to save custom address attribute in customer,checkout shipping and billing form and also save in order table.

**Module Name** : Ccc_Checkout

Script to create custom attribute for address and order

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/Setup/UpgradeData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\Checkout\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        Config $eavConfig,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig            = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory  = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.2','<')) { 
            $this->addUnitNumberFieldToAddress($setup);
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3','<')) { 
            $this->updateUnitAttribute($setup);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();

        
    }

    /**
    * put your comment there...
    * 
    * @param mixed $setup
    */
    protected function addUnitNumberFieldToAddress($setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'unit_number', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Unit Number',
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system'=> false,
            'group'=> 'General',
            'sort_order' => 71,
            'global' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
        ]);       

        $customAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', 'unit_number');

        $customAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'] 
        );
        $customAttribute->save();


        $installer = $setup;


        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('quote_address'),
            'unit_number',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT, 
                'length' => 255,
                'comment' => 'Unit Number'
            ]
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('sales_order_address'),
            'unit_number',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT, 
                'length' => 255,
                'comment' => 'Unit Number'
            ]
        );
    }

    public function updateUnitAttribute($setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'unit_number', 'sort_order', '71');
    }
}
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/etc/di.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
      <plugin disabled="false" name="BillingLayoutProcessor" sortOrder="99" type="Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
  </type>
  <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\BillingAddressManagement">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Ccc_Checkout_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_BillingAddressManagement" sortOrder="10" type="Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\BillingAddressManagement"/>
  </type>
  <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\BillingAddressPersister">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="BillingAddressSave" sortOrder="10" type="Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\BillingAddressPersister"/>
  </type>
  <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Ccc_Checkout_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_ShippingAddressManagement" sortOrder="10" type="Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
     <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="custome_address_attribute_save" instance="Ccc\Checkout\Observer\SaveUnitNumberInOrder"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">    
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="unit_number" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Create Plugin to display custom attribute in checkout billing and shipping form**

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/Plugin/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor**

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Block\Checkout;
use \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor as MageLayoutProcessor;
class LayoutProcessor
{
   protected $_customAttributeCode = 'unit_number';
    public function afterProcess(MageLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'])) 
        {
            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) 
            {                
                $paymentCode = 'billingAddress'.str_replace('-form','',$key);
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children'][$this->_customAttributeCode] = $this->getUnitNumberAttributeForAddress($paymentCode);                
            } 

        }   

         if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])
        ){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$this->_customAttributeCode] = $this->getUnitNumberAttributeForAddress('shippingAddress');
         }

        return $jsLayout;     
    }   

    public function getUnitNumberAttributeForAddress($addressType)
    {        
        return $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [                
                'customScope' => $addressType.'.custom_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
            ],
            'dataScope' => $addressType.'.custom_attributes' . '.' . $this->_customAttributeCode,
            'label' => 'Unit Number',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 71,
            'validation' => [
               'required-entry' => false
            ],
            'options' => [],
            'filterBy' => null,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'visible' => true,
        ];
    }    
}
```

**To save custom attribute in checkout**

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/Plugin/Magento/Quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement**

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model;

class ShippingAddressManagement
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeAssign(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
    ) {

        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();        
        if (!empty($extAttributes)) {
            try {
                $address->setUnitNumber($extAttributes->getUnitNumber());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/Plugin/Magento/Quote/Model/BillingAddressManagement**

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model;

class BillingAddressManagement
{

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeAssign(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\BillingAddressManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address,
        $useForShipping = false
    ) {

        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (!empty($extAttributes)) {
            try {
                $address->setUnitNumber($extAttributes->getUnitNumber());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/Ccc/Checkout/Plugin/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address**

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\Checkout\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;

class BillingAddressPersister
{

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\BillingAddressPersister $subject,
        $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address,
        $useForShipping = false
    ) {

        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (!empty($extAttributes)) {
            try {
                $address->setUnitNumber($extAttributes->getUnitNumber());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**To set custom attribute in extension attribute**

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
             'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address': {
                'Ccc_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Ccc_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address': {
                'Ccc_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'Ccc_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address': {
                'Ccc_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/create-shipping-address-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            if (messageContainer.custom_attributes != undefined) {
                $.each(messageContainer.custom_attributes , function( key, value ) {
                    messageContainer['custom_attributes'][key] = {'attribute_code':key,'value':value};
                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setBillingAddressAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setBillingAddressAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();            
            if(billingAddress != undefined) {

                if (billingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                    billingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
                }

                if (billingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                    $.each(billingAddress.customAttributes, function (key, value) {                        
                        if($.isPlainObject(value)){
                            value = value['value'];
                        }

                        billingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;
                    });
                }

            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            if (shippingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                $.each(shippingAddress.customAttributes , function( key, value ) {

                    if($.isPlainObject(value)){
                        value = value['value'];
                    }
                    shippingAddress['customAttributes'][key] = value;
                    shippingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;

                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

To save custom attribute in orders

**app/code/Ccc/Checkout/Observer/SaveUnitNumberInOrder.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\Checkout\Observer;

class SaveUnitNumberInOrder implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
         if ($quote->getBillingAddress()) {
              $order->getBillingAddress()->setUnitNumber($quote->getBillingAddress()->getExtensionAttributes()->getUnitNumber());
          }
          if (!$quote->isVirtual()) {            
              $order->getShippingAddress()->setUnitNumber($quote->getShippingAddress()->getUnitNumber());
          }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

To display custom attribute in customer account you need to overright customer edit.phtml file from vendor to your theme like below :

**app/design/frontend/custom_theme/theme_name/Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml**

```
<div class="field unit_number">
            <label class="label" for="unit_number"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Unit Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                
                <input type="text" name="unit_number" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('unit_number') ? $block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('unit_number')->getValue() : '') ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('unit_number') ? $block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('unit_number')->getValue() : '') ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('unit_number') ? $block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('unit_number')->getValue() : '') ?>" id="unit_number">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works and help me to understand how to add new attribute on the customer address

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement sales_quote_address_save_after for that

more info you can find 
https://web4pro.net/blog-news/magento-2-add-custom-attribute-customers-address/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was struggling with this for days.

Try adding the etc/fieldset.xml:

```
         <field name="address_email">
             <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
             <aspect name="to_order_address" />
         </field>
     </fieldset>
```

And a plugin for Customer Address:

```
        <plugin disabled="false" name="module_quote_model_address" sortOrder="10" 
        type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Model\Address"/>
    </type>
```

and use the beforeUpdateData function to save your custom attribute.

Hope it helps!